# Print response of PHP script to client terminal

Tags: php, shell, http, curl, server

I have this `.sh` one-liner script:

```
curl http://example.com/script.php
```

`script.php` at the server looks like this:

```
echo "hello"
```

How can I modify the `.sh` script to catch the output of `script.php`?

Comment: Did you try curl http://example.com/script.php >> output.txt ?

Comment: If you're planning on running eval or something on that output I'd suggest it's a bad idea unless you have total control over example.com/script.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I modify the .sh script to catch the output of script.php?

You can capture it in a variable like so:

```
MY_VAR=$(curl -s http://example.com/script.php)
```

Use `-s` to prevent the progress from displaying in stdout. From here you can use `$MY_VAR` to control the output.